# Parse body of msg (email) file

Tags: powershell, outlook, msg

I need to parse the body of emails to get the contents of a table out of each email. I would like to use PowerShell to do this. I have tried this code:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\mmartindale.NTSERVER\Desktop\delreg temp\msg" -Filter *.msg |
    ForEach-Object {
        $outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
        $msg = $outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem($_.FullName)
        $msg | Select body | ft -AutoSize
    }
```

But all I get is an abbreviated output like this:

```
Body
----
This is approved for Deal Reg...
```

How do I output this as an object that I can loop through?

Comment: Hi, try to replace `$msg | Select body|ft -AutoSize` with `$msg | Select -expand body` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object`'s `-ExpandProperty` parameter to expand the property you want.

As in:

```
$msg | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Body
```

Comment: I'm really interested to see if you know of a way to close the $msg after it's been opened. The script will parse the e-mail body 1 time, but after that it complains of the message already being opened.

Comment: @Brandon I'll do some testing. Why do you need to parse it multiple times? I've had this kind of issue with the client, and I think it's related to some security setting in Outlook (Trust Center).

Comment: @Brandon please open a new question with the code you use, I don't know what you mean by "parse it twice", and it shouldn't be dealt with in comments : ).